# Admob Adreward fails to load, error code 0

Tags: android, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

When I tried to load the ad, sometimes it shows the error code 0

```
rewardedAd = new RewardedAd(getActivity(), "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917"); 
RewardedAdLoadCallback adLoadCallback = new RewardedAdLoadCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onRewardedAdLoaded() {
            // Ad successfully loaded
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            // Ad failed to load, I got error code = 0 here
        }
    };
```

In this thread, the author said:

> Error Code 0 : ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR This indicates that something
>   happened internally; for instance, an invalid response was received
>   from the ad server.
>
> Newly created Ad Units can take upto 2 hours to become active (SpinUp
>   Time). Any Ad requests from newly created Ad Units would also receive
>   Error Code 0 in response to Ad requests until they are ready to serve
>   live ads.

I don't think it was the problem cause I used only test ad id.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

**Here are steps to implement reward ads properly in app**

```
private RewardedVideoAd mRewardedVideoAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
     loadRewardedVideoAd();
}

public void loadRewardedVideoAd() {

    mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(new RewardedVideoAdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
          loadRewardedVideoAd();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {


        }
    });

    mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
            new AdRequest.Builder().build());
}

public void showRewardedAds() {
    if (mRewardedVideoAd != null && mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
        mRewardedVideoAd.show();
    }  else {

      loadRewardedVideoAd();
    }
}

 @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (mRewardedVideoAd != null) {
        mRewardedVideoAd.destroy(this);
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```